# How to send Javascript code from Controller to GSP view?

Tags: javascript, grails, rendering

I want to send some JS Script from controller to GSP view . 
I do the following attempt.

**Controller(Purchase.groovy) :**

```
 def myaction={
     flash.script= 'jQuery("div#header").show(1000);'
     redirect(action:'edit')
}
```

In **purchase/myaction.gsp** file,
I try the following code

```
<g:if test="${flash.script !=null}">
    <g:javascript>
    $(function() {

            ${flash.script}
    })
   </g:javascript>
</g:if>
<g:else>
 <g:javascript>
    $(function() {

          alert('Welcome')
    })
   </g:javascript>
</g:else>
```

I try also : `jQuery.getScript('${flash.script}')` instead of `'${flash.script}'`
However, GSP page renders always the second script(else statement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, be sure to call the function after the dom loaded; u can use jquery like

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     call_function();
  });
```

And you can send js code form controller as map, not through flash and redirecting to another action. See below:

```
 def myaction={
    redirect(action:'edit', customJs: 'jQuery("div#header").show(1000);')
 }

 def edit={
   render view: 'someView', model:[customJs: customJs]
}
```

And in view:

```
 <g:javascript>
$(function() {

        <%= customJs %>
})
```

Comment: Passing a customJs as a parameter in redirect is a security hole/XSS

Answer (score 1):

`flash.script` is fine, I tested here and it works. What happens is that `flash` object is for transition, and will be available only in the next request. If your page is redirected to `edit` and you refresh `edit`, then flash will not be there anymore. Example:

- Go to myaction;
- Flow will redirect to edit;
- If you refresh the page, welcome will be printed.